# Find blank count in a row with most blanks within a 2D array of cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want a formula that will look in a 2D array of cells for the row that has the most blank cells in it. Then I want the number of that row's blank cells returned as shown in the picture. The "Title 2" row has the most blanks at 4 as displayed in B8. I would want the formula to take the whole table into considerations, so cells B2:G5

[image: Count Blank Rows Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or this **array formula****:

```
=MAX(MMULT(0+(LEN(B2:G5)=0),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B2:G5)^0)))
```

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: This did the trick! One other quick question: is there a way to do this with uneven cell matrixes all at once? For example, the range of:
B2:G5,B6:D7,B8:F11

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Are we considering individual rows within each of those ranges, as in your first example? Or is it simply counting the total number of blank cells in each of those ranges, then returning the maximum of those three values?

Comment: Yes, still considering individual rows within each range.

Comment: Perhaps something like: =MAX(COUNTIF(OFFSET(B2,{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},,,{6,6,6,6,3,3,5,5,5,5}),""))

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's easier to break things up into two tasks:

1. A formula in `Column H` that counts blanks by row. Something like: `=COUNTIF(B2:G2, "="&"")` which you would drag down through row #5.
2. Then, just make `Cell B8` the maximum of that new column: `=MAX(H2:H5)`.

I'd be curious if there is some type of array formula trick to accomplish this is one formula.  Nevertheless, personally, I find separating the logic into smaller, more manageable, formulas easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

In **H2** enter:

```
=COUNTBLANK(B2:G2)
```

and copy down.  In **B8** enter:

```
=MAX(H2:H5)
```

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Several great answers already, but I'll throw this out there:

```
=MAX(COUNTBLANK(INDIRECT("B"&ROW(2:5)&":"&"G"&ROW(2:5))))
```

Enter as an array formula:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

This:

```
"B"&ROW(2:5)&":"&"G"&ROW(2:5)
```

… returns an array of strings {"B2:G2" , "B3:G3" , "B4:G4" , "B5:G5"}:

That array is fed to the `INDIRECT` function, which changes it into an array of ranges {B2:G2 , B3:G3 , B4:G4 , B5:G5}.

That new array is fed to the `COUNTBLANK` function, which (using your example) returns the array of numbers {2 , 4 , 1 , 3}.

That's fed to the `MAX` function, so the end result is the number **4**.

It's a bit convoluted, so I'm wondering if my `INDIRECT` parameter can be simplified.